# What does it to make a multi-player game on smartphones?

Tags: multiplayer

What precisely do I need to make a multi-player game on smartphones like Blackberry and Android? I know that I have to implement a server by using sockets in Java. How? Can anyone guide me on that?

Comment: you need to accept more answers, people don't spend time here for nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Understand peer-to-peer or star-topology network programming and probably drawing 2D graphics at minimum.

The [C++ ACE](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE.html) library has two books which embodies the knowledge of network programming in great detail. You probably don't need this level of knowledge. My next suggestion is toned down but still a low-level, [C interface](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/), to network programming. You can learn a lot from that. However, it is more tedious than my initial suggestion.

**Note: I am not advocating the use of C++ or C for your work. The references above merely embody the knowledge of network programming.**

If your game does not build on standard GUI elements -- i.e., it has to draw scenes. Then you need to learn about computer graphics. A [standard book](http://books.google.com/books?id=-4ngT05gmAQC&printsec=frontcover&dq=computer+graphics&source=bl&ots=QVKta_gvsb&sig=0161WV4vh2Bp1UfcxZ-q5Ekt9x4&hl=en&ei=IP6US-ehFab20wSavOHgDA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=&f=false) should do.

Comment: Thank you so much for what you have added to my knowledge. But for Android and BB i need to use Java. I already know that i need to do socket programming. Do you suggest that i write an applet game on the web (like Tic Tac Toe) and then jump on smartphones. Well smartphones do not support Swing and AWT. But still i will come to know how to program sockets in Java...am i right? Correct me if i'm wrong. Wonder if there is a tutorial available on making Tic Tac Toe  on smartphone(Android or BB) where sockets are used and server is implemented?

Comment: So far what i can gather is there are 3 modules of a multi player game:
1. Game Invitation Module (Players can invite other players by accessing their contacts and sending emails to people)
2. Game Core Module (e.g. chess, checkers, scrabble , etc.) 
3. Player Registration Module  (Users  will have to register to become players and have to login with an id/screen name).

Please comment and explain.

Comment: You seem to be doing quite well, however we can only advise on specific issues -- not on problems large in scope -- on such problems we can only give vague hints.

Comment: It does not make any sense to build a socket server on your own. There are plenty of turn-key solutions out there.